# Unable to convert string to Json in Python because of unicode characters

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have a String in Python 3.5 from which I'd like to create a Json object. But turns out that the string contains things like this:

```
"saved_search_almost_max_people_i18n":"You are reaching your current limit of saved people searches. \\u003ca href=\\"/mnyfe/subscriptionv2?displayProducts=&family=general&trk=vsrp_ss_upsell\\"\\u003eLearn more &gt;\\u003c/a\\u003e"
```

These unicode characters make the json.loads function fail; actually if I try to format the string as Json in any online formatter, multiple errors show up.

As you can see, I'm a Python newbie, but I've been looking many sources and haven't found any solution. 
By the way, the String comes from a Beautifulsoup operation:

```
soup = self.loadSoup(URL)
result = soup.find('code', id=TAG_TO_FIND)
rTxt=str(result)
j = json.loads(rTxt)
```

The first error I see (if I correct this one, there are many more coming):

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 858 (char 857)
```

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you’re trying to parse an HTML document with Beautiful Soup and extract JSON text out of a particular `code` element in that document.

If so, the following line is wrong:

```
rTxt=str(result)
```

Calling `str()` on a Beautiful Soup [`Tag`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag) returns its HTML representation. Instead, you want the [`string`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) attribute:

```
rTxt=result.string
```

Comment: Actually the problem is parsing the String I get (the one in rTxt). It contains unicode characters like \u003e, and the json parser doesn't like them...

Comment: @vanderflo Can you dump and post the contents of `rTxt`?

Comment: For example: 
    "teamlink_enable_error_text_i18n":"TeamLink search can\xe2\x80\x99t be enabled from here. You can enable it from your \\u003ca href=\\"/settings/?trk=vsrp_tl_optin_fail\\"\\u003eSettings page\\u003c/a\\u003e"

Comment: @vanderflo That is not valid JSON at all; it looks like a snippet from a JSON text. The strings in particular look like JSON strings that have been rendered as Python strings, i.e. the backslash in JSON’s `\u003c` has been escaped by Python, giving `\\u003c`. But even if you fix the escapes, you shouldn’t be able to parse that.

Comment: @vanderflo Can you just post the URL of the document perhaps?